# Drop function in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, identifier, sql-function

I have the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "updateStat"(_request_date timestamp without time zone, _calls integer, _latency integer) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  LOCK TABLE "statistics" IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
  WITH upsert AS (UPDATE "statistics" set calls = calls + _calls, total_latency = total_latency + _latency WHERE request_date=_request_date RETURNING request_date)
  INSERT INTO "statistics" ("request_date", "calls", "total_latency") SELECT _request_date, _calls, _latency WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT "request_date" FROM upsert);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can I drop such function?

I have tried the following:

```
# DROP FUNCTION updateStat(void);
ERROR:  function updatestat(void) does not exist
# DROP FUNCTION updateStat();
ERROR:  function updatestat() does not exist
```

Comment: What do you pass `void` as argument types list ?

Comment: Becouse I though that it needs the return type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DROP FUNCTION "updateStat"(timestamp without time zone, integer, integer);
```

You might want to consider using `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION...` in your create script, so you can redefine it without needing to drop it each time.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it doesnt work for me :(, this is returning `ERROR:  function updatestat(timestamp without time zone, integer, integer) does not exist`. but when I do a `\df` in the CLI this is showing me the function as you describe: [see this image](http://i.imgur.com/XTV3S1S.png)

Comment: @lante even with the quotes ? I left those out of the first edit, sorry. They're necessary to get the mixed case name to work.

Comment: @lante: for details on why you need the quotes, please see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS In general it's better to avoid quoted identifiers alltogether.

Comment: in my case, I created two functions with the same name, one with json param and one with 3 text params. To drop one, in psql (CLI), I typed `DROP FUNCTION my_function(` then I typed _tab_ keyboard key and psql suggest _json_ or _text, text, text_